# Html body not taking full width when switching to mobile device

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a responsive web-page, which works fine on pc view. The problem is when I inspect as a mobile device, the html just gets 3/4 of the screen. I know which CSS class causes the problem, but I can't figure out why (specially because the class just affects a section), and without it a whole section goes away. Does anyone know why it happens or how to fix it?

Further search has revealed that the property causing the problem is:

```css
.rl-section:before {
    position: absolute;
    content:'';
}
```

However, I don't know how to do it in a different way which doesn't cause anything to crash.

Code:

```css
<style type="text/css">
.rl-section {
    position: relative;
    
}
.rl-section:before {
    position: absolute;
    content:'';
}

.rl-diagonal {
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 3em;
}
.rl-diagonal:before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: -3% 0;
    transform-origin: -3% 0;
    top: 0;
    left: -25%;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 150%;
    height: 75%;
    background: inherit;
}
</style>


<style type="text/css">
    
.lr-section {
    position: relative;

}
.lr-diagonal {
    text-align: center;
    -moz-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -o-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    transform: scale(-1, 1);
}
.lr-content {
   -moz-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -o-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    transform: scale(-1, 1);
}
.lr-section:before {
    position: absolute;
    content:'';
}


.lr-diagonal {
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 3em;
}
.lr-diagonal:before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: -3% 0;
    transform-origin: -3% 0;
    top: 0;
    left: -25%;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 150%;
    height: 75%;
    background: inherit;
} 

    
</style>
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="first-section" style="padding: 5px 5px 15px; height: 500px;">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col s6">
            <img src="#">
          </div>
          <div class="col s6">
            <p class="center-align">text</p>
          </div>
      </div>
        
    </div>
    <div class="lr-diagonal lr-section" style="background-color:blue">
      <div class="lr-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rl-diagonal rl-section" style="background-color:black;">
    <div class="lr-content">
        <img src="#">
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I understand what your problem is, but I may be completely off the mark. Does adding `overflow-x: hidden` to your body solve your issue?

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't do anything to it, thanks anyway!. As I commented below the body just takes a fixed % and stays like that no matter what I do (setting meta options to full-screen and all that stuff). As soon as I delete the mentioned classes the problem goes away, I don't know what to do.

Comment: Sorry, I had to put it to modify the whole html so that it worked, but it finally did, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Body take's 8px margin that's why its not taking full width use this.. Thanks

```
body{
    margin: 0px;
   }
```

Comment: Unfortunately I had already tried that, and it doesn't work, thanks anyway. The thing is it always takes a fixed % of the screen, not a fixed margin... I really don't know what may be going on